# Bash string operation

Tags: string, bash, markdown, markup

I am trying to translate markdown file into confluence markup as a complete beginner.
I need to make `[Title](https:// site.com)` into `[Title|https:// site.com]`. If it was just one link, i could add it to a var and printf it, but I am having trouble figuring out how to do it if I have 10 links for example.
Previously I used CONTENT=$(echo "${CONTENT//# /h1. }") to replace strings but since now every string is different, I am stuck at how to solve this. I found the solution written in javascript: http://chunpu.github.io/markdown2confluence/browser but fail to understand how to do it in bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this test file

```
$ cat file
[Title](https://site1.com)
[Title](https://site2.com)
[Title](https://site3.com)
[Title](https://site4.com)
[Title](https://site5.com)
[Title](https://site6.com)
[Title](https://site7.com)
[Title](https://site8.com)
[Title](https://site9.com)
[Title](https://site10.com)
```

Sed variant:

```
$ sed 's/\](/|/;s/)/\]/' file
[Title|https://site1.com]
[Title|https://site2.com]
[Title|https://site3.com]
[Title|https://site4.com]
[Title|https://site5.com]
[Title|https://site6.com]
[Title|https://site7.com]
[Title|https://site8.com]
[Title|https://site9.com]
[Title|https://site10.com]
```

Bash variant:

```
while read -r line; do
    line=${line//](/|}
    line=${line//)/]}
    echo $line
done < file
[Title|https://site1.com]
[Title|https://site2.com]
[Title|https://site3.com]
[Title|https://site4.com]
[Title|https://site5.com]
[Title|https://site6.com]
[Title|https://site7.com]
[Title|https://site8.com]
[Title|https://site9.com]
[Title|https://site10.com]
```

Awk variant:

```
$ awk '{ sub(/\]\(/, "|"); sub(/\)/, "]"); print }' file
[Title|https://site1.com]
[Title|https://site2.com]
[Title|https://site3.com]
[Title|https://site4.com]
[Title|https://site5.com]
[Title|https://site6.com]
[Title|https://site7.com]
[Title|https://site8.com]
[Title|https://site9.com]
[Title|https://site10.com]
```

Comment: Love the options. Didn't OP want a space in the middle of the link, though?

Comment: @PaulHodges : It still works ;-). A space in a URL doesn't seem likely, and most likely a typo? .... Test ... `printf '[Title](https:// site.com)\n' | sed 's/\](/|/;s/)/\]/'` output : `[Title|https:// site.com]` , Good luck to all!
`

Comment: Was my thought, lol

Comment: Yes my space was intentional, stackoverflow editor is blocking Https site.com. thank you very much for the detailed response.